# Designate Excel Data Connection ReadOnly

Tags: excel, properties, readonly, read-write, data-connections

I have an Excel file with a data connection to another Excel source which is referenced by several other reports.  The data connection should be read only, but I cannot seem to setup the properties to do so - whenever the source file is open somewhere else, the data connection attempts to open the source as read-write.  I have tried to enter `ReadOnly=0`,`ReadOnly=TRUE`, and `ReadOnly=1`, but nothing seems to be effective.

When the source file opens, it seems to interrupt my macro which executes as a timer.  The connection string for my data connection is (with substituted paths):

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ="Source File Path";DefaultDir="Directory Path";DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

Comment: Any help on this?  I am still having trouble with all of my reports attempting to open the same data source as Read-Write when it shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the workbooks from the source into the workbook I use them in. For this i use the following code (with **ReadOnly:=True**):

```
'Open workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Workbooks.Open ("location"), UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True

'Copy worksheet
Workbooks(sourceWorkbook).Worksheets(sourceSheet).Copy _
 after:=Workbooks(destinationWorkbook).Worksheets(Workbooks(destinationWorkbook).Worksheets.Count)

'Close source workbook      
Workbooks(sourceWorkbook).Close
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Hope that helps